# File Transfer over ip in vb

Tags: vb.net

in Visual basic there is a function called file copy

```
filecopy(source,destination)
```

is it possible to copy from my computer to another over ip?
ex:

```
filecopy("C:\User\name\Desktop\test.txt",//192.168.x.x)
```

if yes what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Well if that target computer is a `Windows` machine (or it is into `Samba`) with a network shared folder that has write access it works.
On any other constellation you'd need use something like [S]FTP

Comment: I'm not sure about IP but with a computer name it would be: filecopy("C:\User\name\Desktop\test.txt", "\\computerName\c$\User\name\Desktop")

Comment: yes thats exactly what im looking for, however can we replace the name  with a value if we dont what is the user name?

Comment: Just create a shared folder `\\computerName\Shared`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the UNC path correctly, for example:

```
filecopy("C:\User\name\Desktop\test.txt","\\192.168.x.x\c$\User\name\Desktop")
```

Also it's better to use [File.IO.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the old VB6 syntax.